# Replace values in a list depending on value of other list?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists of same length. One representing the actual values, the other some sort of quality values. Depending on the quality threshold (4) I want to replace the values with some other value (p.e. 17). My approach was to iterate over the qualities with `enumerate` to get the index and replace that certain index in values.

*Is there some nicer way to do this?*

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
quality = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

threshold = 4
value = 17

for i, qual in enumerate(quality):
    if qual < threshold:
        values[i] = value

# [17 17 17 17  4  4  4  4  4  4]
print(values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with mask arrays and [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) in [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
values[quality < threshold] = value
```

should do the trick without iteration:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
quality = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

threshold = 4
value = 17

values[quality < threshold] = value

print(values)  # array([17, 17, 17, 17,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4])
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty cool. I used this on other places, but thought it only works with the same array. Thanks!